# Keeping HTML tags in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a pastebin clone. I need the user to be able to type in HTML without it being used like HTML. For example, my user types "`<html> Hello, world! </html>`", and the html tags don't appear because the text is being treated like HTML. I do not want this to happen.

I want this to happen to this line:

```
<%=simple_format(@post.content )%>
```

How could I accomplish this? I tried using raw and .html_safe and they didn't work.

Comment: So you want the tags to be displayed as plain text? In that case `raw` and `html_safe` will do the exact opposite of what you want.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be displayed as plain text.

Comment: Why aren't you just rendering the string… `<%= @post.content %>`? Does that not work?

Comment: 'raw' will run it as html. you could wrap in a 'pre' tag or use a syntax highlighting gem

Comment: It works, but I want to keep the post in a simple_format style. so that if the user types in 2 lines, the parts of each line stay on their own line.

Comment: As Andrew and Kyle said, you don't need `simple_format`, just drop it, render the contents (they'll get HTML escaped) and wrap into a `<pre>` tag (so the line breaks are preserved). You'll get the exact format you need. Then fire up a syntax highlighting gem and you're golden. Sometimes all you need is to remove code, not write more.

Answer (score 0):

The SanitizeHelper module provides a set of methods for scrubbing text of undesired HTML elements. These helper methods extend Action View making them callable within your template files.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Comment: I want to do the opposite of this and keep the HTML tags in simple_format.